# How to find common words in multiple files

Tags: excel, bash

I have 4 text files that contain server names as follows: (each file had about 400 lines in with various server names)

```
Server1
Server299
Server140
Server15
```

I would like to compare the files and what I want to find is server names common to all 4 files.

I've got no idea where to start - I've got access to Excel, and Linux bash. Any clever ideas?

I've used vlookup in excel to compare 2 columns but dont think this can used for 4 columns?

Comment: See http://www.ehow.com/how_5891017_calculate-text-range-ms-excel.html and http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/286826-most-common-word-excel-column.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to say:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==4 {print $2}'
```

Another way:

```
comm -12 <(comm -12 <(comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)) <(sort file3)) <(sort file4)
```